# Using html to show images

Tags: html, image, onclick, click

I am trying to create a little programme in html.

basically I have a series of images together. my idea is to have the images opacity set to 0 till a user clicks the page.

when they do one of the images will be shown and when they click again the next image will be shown

how easy would this be

the majority I see involve JS which is a coding language i struggle with

Comment: Not possible when using pure HTML without Javascript or jQuery. You need to learn JS :)

Comment: HTML is markup - not a programming language so you can't program with it. You could potentially use the pseudo focus state of an image to show/hide, but not to bring another image in. You be a lot better spending some time learning how to do this with javascript. You can make your life easier by using a library such as jQuery which has lots of plugins for this type of effect.

Comment: great to know thanks. i have a brief understanding of the onclick event. what would i select though as the device being clicked to show the image? as there is no actual button or anything - how would i define the page being clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.onclick` or `document.onclick` to handle a user clicking the page. Note this will require JavaScript.

Try something like this:

```
var curImage = 0;
var images = ["image1","image2","image3"];

function windowClick() {
    document.getElementById(images[curImage]).style.opacity = "0";
    if(curImage < images.length - 1)
    {
        document.getElementById(images[curImage + 1]).style.opacity = "1";
        curImage++;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(images[0]).style.opacity = "1";
        curImage = 0;
    }
}

window.onclick = windowClick;
```

If you use my code as it is, you will have to assign an `id` to each of the images you want to switch between and put these `id`s into the `images` array.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4f1tkv9/2/

Comment: Please put the relevant part of your solution in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
heres what i have so far:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    color: red;
    background-color: #1F2A22;
}

h1 {
    color: #00ff00;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="fans6" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="fans6.png">
<img id="impact6" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="impact6.png">
<img id="text6" IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text6.png">
<img id="panel7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel7.png">
<img id="atom7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="atom7.png">
<img id="fantext7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text fan7.png">
<img id="text7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text7.png">
<img id="fans7"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="fans7.png">
<img id="panel8"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel8.png">
<img id="bang8"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="bang8.png">
<img id="panel9"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel9.png">
<img id="reporter9"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="reporter9.png">
<img id="text9"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text9.png">
<img id="panel10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel10.png">
<img id="full10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="panel full10.png">
<img id="text10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="text10.png">
<img id="end10"IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35px; LEFT:170px; WIDTH:800px; HEIGHT:600px" SRC="the end10.png">

<script>

var curImage = 0;
var images = ["fans6","impact6","text6"];

function windowClick() {
    document.getElementById(images[curImage]).style.opacity = "0";
    if(curImage < images.length - 1)
    {
        document.getElementById(images[curImage + 1]).style.opacity = "1";
        curImage++;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(images[0]).style.opacity = "1";
        curImage = 0;
    }
}

window.onclick = windowClick;

</script>

what i would like is the image to remain once i click and the next image to then come in.

im sure its a simple fix and im just being stupid
```